# Rubymotion, ProMotion ... How to create a list in a view

Tags: rubymotion

Where are methods like numberOfLines:, text:, etc defined?  Are they part of RubyMotion?
Is there a method for creating a list?  How can I create a list in ruby motion...more specifically ProMotion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of those are Objective-C methods. You can see the API reference here:

http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/index.html

For ProMotion, look at the README, specifically the Table Screens portion:

https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/#table-screens

There are also a few screencasts which will help you a lot:

https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/#tutorials

If you're having a problem, feel free to file a GitHub issue on ProMotion and someone will help you fairly quickly. We try to be very helpful to newbies, since we're not that far removed from being newbies ourselves. :)